# TeeChart Data source as Excel file for the series

Tags: activex, teechart

Can anyone help me out with how can I read Series Data ( X, Y and Series Naane) In Teechart from excel. I tried with CSeriesTextSource to read a Data.xls file but was not successful.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 1):

You can create a csv from your xls and then import this csv with `CSeriesTextSource` as in the example published [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=13580&p=59481&hilit=xls#p59481).

EDIT: Here it is the code from that post:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()    
  TChart1.Aspect.View3D = False  
  TChart1.Axis.Bottom.Labels.Style = 2 'talValue
  TChart1.Axis.Left.Logarithmic = True

  TChart1.AddSeries scFastLine
  TChart1.AddSeries scFastLine
  TChart1.AddSeries scPoint
  TChart1.AddSeries scPoint
  TChart1.Series(0).XValues.DateTime = True
  TChart1.Series(1).XValues.DateTime = True
  TChart1.Series(2).XValues.DateTime = True
  TChart1.Series(3).XValues.DateTime = True

  With SeriesTextSource1
    .FileName = "C:\tmp\Data.csv"
    .HeaderLines = 1
    .FieldSeparator = ";"

    .Series = TChart1.Series(0)
    .AddField "X", 1
    .AddField "Y", 2
    .Active = True

    .Series = TChart1.Series(1)
    .AddField "X", 3
    .AddField "Y", 4
    .Active = True

' This works with v2012, but with v8
'    .Series = TChart1.Series(2)
'    .AddField "X", 5
'    .AddField "Y", 6
'    .Active = True
'
'    .Series = TChart1.Series(3)
'    .AddField "X", 7
'    .AddField "Y", 8
'    .Active = True
  End With

' I add the values manually in v8:
  TChart1.Series(2).AddXY CDate("10/11/2003"), 0, "", clTeeColor
  TChart1.Series(3).AddXY CDate("01/02/1999"), 231.48, "", clTeeColor
End Sub

Private Sub TChart1_OnClick()
  Caption = "Min: " + FormatDateTime(TChart1.Axis.Bottom.MinVisibleSeriesValue(True, 0)) + ", Max: " + FormatDateTime(TChart1.Axis.Bottom.MaxVisibleSeriesValue(True, 0))
End Sub
```

You can download the csv with the data for testing [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/download/file.php?id=2988).

Comment: Hi,The link provided for the example says connection refused.

Comment: It works for me. It may have been a problem with the server. I'll edit the answer copying the code from there.